# Mapping not working with address type

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ropsten, mapping

The following code works, that is, I can call `add(2,3)` and then `get(2,0)` returns 3:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Bar {
    struct Foo{
        uint x;
    }
    mapping(uint => Foo[]) foo;

    function add(uint id, uint _x) public {
        foo[id].push(Foo(_x));
    }

    function get(uint id, uint index) view public returns(uint){
        return foo[id][index].x;
    }
}
```

This code does not work, that is, I call `add(0xB139e6071772FAdC0e1Ad79C63415a2866fD447F,3)`, and then `get(0xB139e6071772FAdC0e1Ad79C63415a2866fD447F,0)` returns `0`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Bar {
    struct Foo{
        uint x;
    }
    mapping(address => Foo[]) foo;

    function add(address id, uint _x) public {
        foo[id].push(Foo(_x));
    }

    function get(address id, uint index) view public returns(uint){
        return foo[id][index].x;
    }
}
```

The only difference is that the uint type has been swapped with the address type in a couple of spots.

Comment: This exact code works fine for me in Remix. If you're still having trouble, please describe how you're deploying the contract and how you're calling the functions. (Share code if you're calling the functions from code.)

Comment: If you're using Remix, be sure to enclose the address in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to enclose the address in double quotes when using remix as smarx said